# CSS is not changing in jsp file

Tags: java, css, web

The issue is changing the styles of a page with CSS in jsp the code of linking is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/Profile.css" />
```

This works perfectly fine at the first time and the jsp is styled with the external CSS linking but when I change something it wont appear in the browser even after clean and build for example :
a div have a colour of blue and I change to red it wont show up it just shows blue instead of red.

The browser I'm using is Firefox developer .

Is there any work around for this ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Where did you put the ```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/Profile.css" />``` in the code?

Comment: Thank you well i did put in on head of the jsp where i think its supposed to be ?      <head>
      href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/Profile.css" />
    </head>

Comment: Read the "Multiple Style Sheets" part of: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp ,Maybe it will help. Otherwise we would need to see the whole code to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks so much i almost forgot about the simple rule of  "If some properties have been defined for the same selector (element) in different style sheets, the value from the last read style sheet will be used. " . I think now i know what's the issue is thanks a lot .

Comment: No problem, let me know if it worked. I'll then write the comment as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: No problem. :-) Would appreciate if you would accept my answer as helpful.

Comment: i did , and again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the "Multiple Style Sheets" part of: [www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) ,Maybe it will help. Otherwise we would need to see the whole code to be able to help.